# Redirect to secondary host when primary host is unavailable in Ocelot API Gateway (C#, .NET Core, Ocelot)

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, api-gateway, service-discovery, ocelot

I would like to use Ocelot API Gateway to connect services, but if the primary host is unavailable it needs to redirect to secondary host.

For example in below configuration i have two ports one is 5023 and 5102, So when 5023 is unavailable i want it to redirect to 5102.

Please help, Thanks in advance.

**configuration.json**

```
{
  "Routes": [
    {
       "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/GetProductDetails",
       "DownstreamScheme": "http",
       "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
         {
           "Host": "localhost",
           "Port": 5023
         },
         {
           "Host": "localhost",
           "Port": 5102
         }
       ],

       "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/",
       "LoadBalancerOptions": {
         "Type": "RoundRobin" 
       },
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "GET" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
using Ocelot.DependencyInjection;
using Ocelot.Middleware;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile(
"configuration.json",optional:false,reloadOnChange:true);

builder.Services.AddOcelot(builder.Configuration);

var app = builder.Build();


app.MapControllers();

var ocelotConf = new OcelotPipelineConfiguration()
{
    PreErrorResponderMiddleware = async (context, next) =>
    {
        if (context.Response != null)
        {

        }
        await next.Invoke();
    }
};

await app.UseOcelot(ocelotConf);

app.Run();
```

Either can we write custom load balancer?

Comment: Don't you want it to _proxy_ the request instead of redirecting it?

Comment: Hello Dai, For those two ports am working for load balancing for example if the first port is unavailable we have to get the request by second port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after thinking so much i have understood that from request pipeline we can process to next invoke if the current host is not active.

**Code is below.**

```
var ocelotConf = new OcelotPipelineConfiguration()
{
    PreErrorResponderMiddleware = async (context, next) =>
    {
        // Initial invoke
        await next.Invoke();
        if (context.Response != null)
        {
            // Checking if the initial invoke is throwing 502
            //(Means service is down)
            if(context.Response.StatusCode == 502)
            {
                // If service is down forwarding to next host
                await next.Invoke();
            }
        }
    }
};

await app.UseOcelot(ocelotConf);
```